# Why slug param don't work after build app ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I faced with problem, after build my application my page with slug field doesn't work ex: /detail-game/game-name. During development mode all work perfectly.

err

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' 2.e8c1c89d.chunk.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' main.41c02d6d.chunk.js:1
```

router in the app

```
  <Provider store={Store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
              <Route path="/detail-game/:slug" component={DetailGame} />
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

nginx conf

```
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded>

            alias /home/<my_path>/build/>
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

What I doing wrong? Thanks!

P.S: If apply hash router instead browser router work perfectly, but google engine can't analyze page, because for him, this is not canonical page. (problem in '#')

Comment: I would like to see some more of the _router in the app_ code_ I am sure you are doing this but want to confirm you are defining slug   `let { slug } = useParams()` - Maybe more code can be posted because the unexpected token can be due to variety of reasons. If you want to rule out `nginx` you can directly run a prod build in local and confirm if you are facing the same issue.

Comment: Problem was fixed. Was did small changes and name of game in url looks like get param: /detail-game?game=<game_name>